# How to write where clause for quantitative column or date column parameters in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is the question: I need create a get table stored procedure, and I have many quantitative columns or date columns, like

```
Weight DECIMAL NULL
Cost MONEY NULL
Wattage INT NULL
```

And when I use

```
Create PROCEDURE TABLE.P
   @Weight DECIMAL 
   @Cost MONEY 
   @Wattage INT 

   Select 
       Weight, Cost, Wattage 
   From 
       Table
    Where 
       Weight= or @Weight is null
       and Cost=
```

I don't know how to write the where clause, I know I should use BETWEEN function but how to write it for quantitative or date columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Between works the same regardless of column type.  e.g. `where field between lowValue and highValue`.

Comment: If you want values between two values; you have to pass in the two values; e.g. `select * from table where weight between @lowWeight and @highWeight`.  If you just want an equals you can do `select * from table where weight = @weight`.  If you want to allow for rounding error you can do `select * from table where floor(weight) = floor(@weight)`; loads of other options available depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks, so if I use the BETWEEN, I should create the Upper and Lower value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use BETWEEN you'll need upper and lower values of course. To take what you've shown in the question and filter on equality for any passed values (and ignore any which weren't passed or which were passed as NULL), try something like this:

```
SELECT Weight, Cost, Wattage
FROM Table
WHERE (@Weight IS NULL OR Weight = @Weight)
  AND (@Cost IS NULL OR Cost = @Cost)
  AND (@Wattage IS NULL OR Wattage = @Wattage)
```

A BETWEEN query will have a few more conditions, but the general concept of *`(parameter IS NULL OR condition-using-not-null-parameter)`* still holds.